# D3.js: Hover over animation map

Tags: dictionary, animation, d3.js

Is it possible to add a mouseover function to this sample map:

http://bl.ocks.org/rgdonohue/9280446

Appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this by adding mouseover/mouseout on the part where you apply the choropleth.  But must use a global  tag to add a tooltip:

```
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

//apply choropleth
d3.select("#counties").selectAll(".county")
    .attr("fill", function (d) {
        return getColor(d.properties[attributeArray[currentAttribute]], dataRange);
    })
    .on("mouseover", function (d) {
        d3.select(this)
        div.transition()
            .duration(300)
        div.text(d.properties.County)
            .style("opacity", 1)
            .style("class", "cntyLabel")
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function (d) {
        div.transition()
            .duration(300)
            .style("opacity", 0);
    })
```